# How do I go back on a review?

Tags: support

I was reviewing Answers from new users to old questons. The answer was essentially a thank you comment. While I meant to flag it and then press done, I got distracted by something. Result? Forgot to flag and clicked on the wrong button.

What can I do now? Am I able to re-review that "answer", or have any other influence to fix my mistake?

Answer (score 7):

You can't go back. You can, however, go to the actual question/answer and do any flagging etc that needs to be done. You just can't do anything more in the queue itself once you've pressed the done button.